# A reference variable's address and value C++

Tags: c++, reference

I just found out reference variables and have few questions which is sort of bugging me. Please see the code below.

```
int a = 3;      // &a is 0x28fee
int b = 5;      // &b is 0x16faa
int &ref = a;   // &ref is 0x28fee
ref = b;        // value of ref = 5, address is still 0x28fee
```

I know that a reference variable's address cannot be changed once set, but when I run the command, how is my reference's value changed, but the address is the same?

And since the address is the same as, shouldn't the value of ref still be 3, or maybe shouldn't a's value change into 5, because how can one address have two values?

Lastly, is it correct to assume that the "&" sign is same the one we use in pointers?

Comment: The misunderstanding may be that you believe you are taking the address of a *variable*, which is not true. Rather, you are taking the address of a *value* (of a glvalue to be precise), and the value obtained by evaluating a reference is the one bound to the reference.

Comment: A reference doesn't have to be actually stored in a memory location at all. Even saying it's taking the address isn't quite right. The compiler is free in the above code to never even create a memory location for `ref` and instead substitute `a` everywhere `ref` is used.

Comment: reference is just renaming a variable name..Reference has no memory..For more visit this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_references.htm

Comment: note that `type & name` is the format for a reference.  `& name` is using the address of operator and giver you a pointer to the variable `name`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I know that a reference variables's address cannot be changed once
>   set,

References have nothing to do with addresses. Don't think of references as special pointers.

Unless you are talking about how a **compiler might implement references**. But this is a completely different level of abstraction. On a C++ programmer level, you are not looking at the language from the same point of view as a compiler writer; there is no such thing as a "reference variable's address". Objects have addresses, and a reference is just a different way to name an object.

Or, as I like to explain it to beginners, a reference *is* the object.

> but when I run the command how is my reference's value change but
>   the address is the same?

In the following line:

> ```
> int &ref = a;   //&ref is 0x28fee
> ```

You are declaring `ref` to be a reference to `a`. Using the explanation from above, **`ref` is `a`**. So when you then go on and write `&ref` afterwards (using the `&` character to invoke the address-of operator, rather than declaring a reference), what happens is equivalent to what happens when writing `&a`. It is therefore not surprising that the result is identical. It's one and the same object, so the address must be the same.

> ```
> ref = b;        //value of ref = 5, address is still 0x28fee
> ```

This is the same as writing `a = b;`. It assigns the value of `b` to `a`, because `ref` is just another way to say `a`. No addresses are changed when values are assigned to `int`s.

> Lastly, is it correct to assume that the "&" sign is same the one we
>   use in pointers?

No, not at all. Reiterating my point from above: `&` has different meanings in C++. You use it to declare references *or* to take addresses of objects. Actually, there are even more meanings, considering that `&` is also the bit-wise AND operator, as in `a & b`. Pairs of `&`, i.e. `&&`, extend the list of possible meanings to include the logical AND operator and C++11 rvalue references.

---

From a teaching point of view, it is of course unfortunate that `&` is overloaded for reference declarations and the address-of operator. As far as I know, `&` was chosen for references because back then, it was difficult to add new keywords (like `ref`) to C++ as backward compatibility with C was a huge concern at that time, and adding `ref` as a keyword would have meant that C code like `int ref = 0;` would no longer compile.

C++ had to introduce at least some new keywords (e.g. `throw`), but in certain cases it was technically possible and/or politically necessary to do without them.

Comment: great asnwer @ChristianHackl, this cleared all my doubts and also gave me some more info on the background of c++.

Comment: As an addendum, and to expand on his compiler note: Most compilers will typically implement references in one of two ways, depending on locality.  If the referenced object is visible where the reference is declared, the compiler will typically silently replace the reference with the referenced object (in this case, think of it like copy-pasting `a` wherever it sees `ref`).  If the referenced object isn't visible where the reference is declared, then the reference will typically be implemented as a pointer, but with normal access semantics.

Answer (score 3):

> when I run the command how is my reference's value change but the address is the same?

reference is an alias, when you assign value to `ref` you actually assign it to variable `a`. Why would you expect address to change?

> or maybe shouldn't a's value change into 5

this is correct, when you change value of reference `ref` in your example, you can as well substitiute `ref` to `a`, so you have `a = b`.

> Lastly, is it correct to assume that the "&" sign is same the one we use in pointers?

I am not sure what you ask here, `&` is used to designate that you want a reference, it is not used here to take address of variable `a`.

Comment: you had the right idea about my & question. I was confused with that part the most. Thanks