# Does taking the address of a reference robustly return the address of the underlying aliased object?

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

If a C++ program uses the & operator to take the address of an object referred to via a reference, will the returned address robustly be that of the underlying aliased object or is it possible that it might refer to a temporary instance of the object?

For example:

```
T a[2];

void g(T& b) {assert ((&b + 1) == &a[1]); }

int main () { g(a[0]); return 0; }
```

Does the C++ standard warrant that the above assertion is always true, or is it possible, say for the purposes of optimization, that the compiler might create a temporary of a[0], have b refer to the temporary and then when g returns, load the value of the temporary back into a[0]?

I acknowledge the following statement in [Is always the address of a reference equal to the address of origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821678/is-always-the-address-of-a-reference-equal-to-the-address-of-origin)  However, no reference is given to support the assertion and I am not sure whether it is unconditionally true or not.

> As per the C++ standard it is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage. On the other hand it also says that taking the address of a reference gives you the address of the referent. Hence even if the compiler chooses to have a separate storage for the reference than the referent internally, it would be guaranteed to the programmer that their addresses are the same.

I acknowledge that this and the multitude of other answers like it are almost certainly true.  However, what are the specific provisions of the C++ standard that require conforming compilers to function in this way?  For example, can anyone give me an answer of the form "Section X of ISO/IEC DIS 14882, Programming Languages C++, requires that when the & operator is applied to a reference the resulting rvalue points to the referenced object and Section Y of the Standard requires that if a pointer points to a non-terminal object in an array, then the rvalue pointer + 1 points to the next object in the array and consequently the assertion set out above is unconditionally true."

Comment: One thing to note is that `operator &` for class types does not have to give you the address.  If you want to portably always get the address, use [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof)

Comment: *"it is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage"* -- This is saying that the compiler is allowed to implement a reference as a pointer (as mentioned in [an answer to the proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3494657)); it is not permission to copy the referred-to object. (Of course, the as-if rule allows many optimizations.)

Comment: [Is always the address of a reference equal to the address of origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821678/is-always-the-address-of-a-reference-equal-to-the-address-of-origin) and [Memory address of reference variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494458/memory-address-of-reference-variable)

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "reference variable's address"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36375984/12002570)

Comment: @NathanOliver you don't mean "portably" you mean "even if operator& is overloaded"

Comment: @Xaxxon: In the context of this question the & operator performs its default function of "give me a pointer to".

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1

Comment: @user17732522  thanks.  I think that reference answers my question in the authoritative manner that I needed.  For the benefit of others who might look at this question, I quote Section 7.2.2, paragraph 1 of the draft standard [link](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1) "If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis.  The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression."

Answer (score 0):

"Does taking the address of a reference robustly return the address of the underlying aliased object?" - Yes!

If you take the address of a reference, what you get is the address of the referenced object.

Comment: But would a compiler be in conformance with the standard if it passed a copy of the referenced object to a function, compiled & operations within the function to return the address of the copy, and then copied the copy back to the original when the function returned?  I need references to the standard so that I can be assured of an authoritative answer.

Comment: The "as if" rule pretty much covers that. If the program cannot tell the difference between an optimization being applied or not, then it's allowed.

Comment: @Jonno The compiler can't break standard conforming code.  If you were working with a copy  the compiler would have to add to code to make the address comparison be true since it must be true.

Comment: But what are the words of the standard in this respect?  Can you quote the words or provide a link to the words?

Comment: @Jonno It is a combo of things, [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.ref#5) and [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary.op#3.2).  1 says you cant have a pointer to a reference and 2 says with `&`you get a pointer to `T`, so you must get a pointer to what the reference refers to and not the reference itself.

Answer (score -1):

In C++, when you use the `&` operator to take the address of an object referred to via a reference, you get the address of the underlying object, not a temporary. The C++ standard specifies that when you take the address of a reference, you get the address of the referenced object.

In your example code:

```cpp
T a[2];

void g(T& b) {
    assert((&b + 1) == &a[1]);
}

int main() {
    g(a[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The assertion `(&b + 1) == &a[1]` should always be true according to the C++ standard. The `&b` gives you the address of the object referred to by the reference `b`, and adding 1 to it effectively gives you the address of the next object in memory. Therefore, it should be the same as `&a[1]` if `b` refers to `a[0]`.

In the context of the C++ standard, the compiler should not create a temporary and perform the optimization you mentioned, as taking the address of a reference is meant to give you the address of the referenced object directly. However, keep in mind that some optimizations may be performed by the compiler, but they should not affect the validity of your assertion in this specific case.

Comment: I gather that what you have written is probably correct, but I need references to the sections of the standard that "prove" that what you've written can be sustained.  Excuse me being a bit legalistic here, but when you're relying on something you can easily wind up in a situation where someone asks why did you rely on that when all you had was rumor on which to base your belief.